# select where table < 400 giving erratic values

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
$sql = "(SELECT * FROM   table1 WHERE col1 LIKE  '%Computers%'
AND PRICE <= 400
AND  BUYURL IS NOT NULL
AND  IMAGEURL IS NOT NULL )
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM  table2 WHERE col2 LIKE  '%desktop computer%' 
AND PRICE <= 400
AND  BUYURL IS NOT NULL
AND  IMAGEURL IS NOT NULL )
ORDER BY  PRICE ASC";
```

above query is returning value with 'Price' sometimes more than 400.
can anyone help?
thanks.

Comment: What type the `price` column is?

Comment: Check the column type like zerkms says and try each query on its own. Table1 and Table2 are actually different tables, right?

Comment: @sanjay: varchar is for text types

Comment: If it's varchar then it will sort alphabetically, so 1000 comes before 400. Price should probably be NUMERIC to allow for cents, unless you're only dealing with a currency that doesn't have such a concept (ie Yen) then you could use an int column.

Comment: Try something like `PRICE <= '400'`

Comment: NUMERIC is still useful for values that would overflow an INT.

Answer (score 4):

As a temporary solution you could use:

```
AND CONVERT(price, DECIMAL) <= 400
```

But I **strongly** recommend you to change it so something like `DECIMAL(10,2)` (where 2 is the amoung of digits after the point you want to store)